# How do I get a selection with Text - RichEditBox C++

Tags: c++, winapi, richeditbox

Alright so I know how to make a make a selection with min-max character position, but if you add text then you have to re-find the text and update the selection. So I was searching and found you can use FindTextEx to type in a word, min/max search position and it will return the min/max of that word.

But it always fails for me and I do not know why, also MSDN says for backward search to use FR_DOWN but when I type that in as a (WPARAM) attribute it says it's undefined (Like 50% of the other FR_ listed on FindTextEx page)

RichEdit.h is included (This is just a function because my program currently is too big to post the whole source code)

```
 void UpdateLog() {

    CHARFORMAT CharFormat;
    CharFormat.cbSize = sizeof(CHARFORMAT);
    CharFormat.dwMask = CFM_BOLD | CFM_EFFECTS;
    CharFormat.dwEffects = CFE_BOLD | CFE_AUTOCOLOR;

    std::wstring szUpdatesString;

    szUpdatesString += L"SQL Manager V1.3 - Trevin Corkery\r\n\r\n";
    szUpdatesString += L"New:\r\nAdded \"Information\" Tab\r\n\r\n";
    szUpdatesString += L"Improvements:\r\n\r\n";
    szUpdatesString += L"Fixes:\r\nTabs now work correctly.\r\n";
    SetWindowText(hUpdatesRE, szUpdatesString.c_str());
    CHARRANGE CharRange = { 0 };
    FINDTEXTEX FindTextExtended;

    FindTextExtended.chrg.cpMin = 0;
    FindTextExtended.chrg.cpMax = -1;
    FindTextExtended.lpstrText = L"New";


    SendMessage(hUpdatesRE, EM_FINDTEXTEX, FR_NOT_ENUM, (LPARAM)&FindTextExtended);
    SendMessage(hUpdatesRE, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&CharFormat);

}
```

Comment: Fails how? `EM_FINDTEXTEX` returns the position of the start of the match, and in your code you aren't using the return value at all.

Comment: I know, that's because if it "returns" that it hasn't found the selected text it returns -1 for both cpMin and cpMax. 

I am not using it, simply because it doesn't return anything. I am just checking the return value in the debugger.

Comment: According to the docs you should be using EM_FINDTEXTEXW for Unicode. Have you tried that?

Comment: In other words you are asking us to help you with something, but not giving us all the facts. We don't know what debugging you are doing. The overwhelming majority of winapi questions here involve the asker ignoring important return values. Forgive us for being sceptical that you are not doing the same.

Comment: I did not intentionally leave out the information to make all of you to fill in a blanks it was a simple mistake but it's fine now, I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out the problem, I had the wrong attribute for WPARAM. It required FR_DOWN, but seeing as FR_DOWN was undefined for some strange reason I looked up the code for FR_DOWN and found it was 0x00000001.

This now works,

```
SendMessage(hUpdatesRE, EM_FINDTEXT, (WPARAM)0x00000001, (LPARAM)&FindTextExtended)
```